# Get numerical values from string input in Python

Tags: python, list, function

I need to make a function that takes a string as input and outputs a list of all numerical values.

Some examples:

- `"22-28, 31-35, 37"` should output: `[22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37]`
- `"22, 24"` should output: `[22, 24]`
- `"23"` should output: `[23]`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try regular expressions.

```
import re
r = re.findall('[0-9]+-[0-9]+|[0-9]+',string)
ans = []
for i in r:
    if '-' in i:
        t = i.split('-')
        ans.extend(range(int(t[0]),int(t[1])))
    else:
        ans.append(int(i))
print ans
```

Answer (score 1):

Without regular expressions:

```
def text_range(s):
    res = []
    for pc in s.split(','):
        if '-' in pc:  # this assumes no negative numbers in the list!
            a,b = [int(i) for i in pc.split('-')]
            res.extend(range(a, b+1))
        else:
            res.append(int(pc))
    return res
```

then

```
text_range("22-28, 31-35, 37")    # -> [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37]
```